# Online stores for second hand photo equipment in France

Tags: used-equipment, online-shopping, europe

What are the biggest reputable online camera stores in France that offer used equipment for sale?  Is there anything similar to keh.com either in France or in nearby countries (with affordable, customs-free shipping to France)?

Comment: I came to France recently and I am not yet familiar with the local situation.

Comment: If you buy electronics/photographic equipment from an online shop in any EU member state, there is no customs duty payable, so you might consider buying equipment from the UK for example. (You would have to take the current euro/sterling exchange rate into consideration in that case of course.)

Comment: @osullic Thanks, yes, I know that, that's why I asked also about nearby countries.  But the question still stands: which stores do people use here?

Comment: There is www.mpbphotographic.co.uk here in England, I don't know what delivery to France would be like

Answer (score 1):

Two of the most famous online camera store for used equipment in France are **Objectif Bastille** (http://www.objectif-bastille.com/) and **Phox** (http://www.phox-occasion.com/).

Both have physicals stores and their used products come with a 6 month warranty (at least for bodys and lenses). I bought one used lense from "Objectif Bastille" 18 month ago and have still no problem with it. A friend bought his body from Phox (about 2 years ago) and is still happy with it.

If you are looking for non-professional website (and speak French), you can try **Le Bon Coin** (www.leboncoin.fr/), it's a website similar to craigslist where each person can add a "for sale" post. As usual with such website, you should take precautions when buying.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [eBay France](http://www.ebay.fr) and [PriceMinister](http://www.priceminister.com) .
On Priceminister, people often have no idea what they're selling so you can find interesting prices.
Both will offer you buyer protection and as far as eBay is concerned, often low prices.
You can also stay tuned to your local [Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org) and [Le Bon Coin](http://www.leboncoin.fr) which was already mentioned.